# adding a MouseListener to two adjacents JComponent, Bug

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouselistener

I created a component Named `FAdjacentTooltips`, which show information about another JComponent (JLabel,JPanel...), when the mouse enter to this one and disappear when the mouse exit it, here is the events initialisation in the `FAdjacentToolTips` class:

```
this.holderComponent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        FAdjacentToolTips.this.setSize(0, 0);
        FAdjacentToolTips.this.revalidate();
        FAdjacentToolTips.this.repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered
            (MouseEvent e) {
        if (!activationFlag) {
            FAdjacentToolTips.this.build();
            activationFlag = true;
        }
        FAdjacentToolTips.this.setSize(toolTypeWidth, toolTypeHeight);
        FAdjacentToolTips.this.revalidate();
        FAdjacentToolTips.this.repaint();
    }
});
```

when the mouse enter to the JComponent : `holderComponent`, the FAdjacentToolTips is set to a given size, and when the mouse exit the `holderComponent` the FAdjacentToolTips size is set to zero.

It work well when adding  `FAdjacentToolTips` to one component, but having issue 
when adding it to two Adjacents JComponents (One near another), here is an example with two JLabel

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 700));
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    CustomLabel firstLabel = new CustomLabel("first Label", Color.yellow);
    firstLabel.setLocation(100, 100);

    CustomLabel secondeLabel = new CustomLabel("second Label", Color.blue);
    secondeLabel.setLocation(100, 300);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));
    panel.setBackground(Color.red);

    panel.add(secondeLabel);
    panel.add(firstLabel);

    firstLabel.addFAdjacentToolTip("AAAAAAAA", FAdjacentToolTipable.LEFT_OF_CONTAINER);
    secondeLabel.addFAdjacentToolTip("BBBBB", FAdjacentToolTipable.LEFT_OF_CONTAINER);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));
    frame.getRootPane().getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


class CustomLabel extends JLabel implements FAdjacentToolTipable {

    public CustomLabel(String text, Color color) {
        super(text);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void addFAdjacentToolTip(String text, int side) {
        FAdjacentToolTips fAdjacentToolTips = new FAdjacentToolTips(this, text, side, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, Color.black, this.getFont());
        fAdjacentToolTips.activate();

    }
}
```

firstLabel is on the top of secondLabel, here is the issue behavior:

- it work well when moving the mouse from the outside to one of the labels, the FAdjacentToolTips appear/disappear when the mouse Enter/Exit the labels
- when moving the mouse from `firstLabel` to `secondLabel`, the firstLabel FAdjacentToolTips disappear (as needed) but the `secondLabel` FAdjacentToolTips don't appear.

after many testing here the informations I had gathered:

even if the FAdjacentToolTips don't show up on the screen, the mouseEnter method is called, and the **size is set correctly**.

My question is: Why the FAdjacentToolTips don't show up when moving from one label to another, even if the events are triggered well, and the size is set correctly?

here is a   runnable of a test programme :
here is the source code :http://www.filedropper.com/javatest
here is the runnable : http://www.filedropper.com/javatest_1

to understand my problem :
1-try to move the mouse from the JFrame to one of the labels.
2-try to move the mouse from one label to another

please tell me if you need more informations.

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve] -- a SMALL program with code that **we** can compile and run unmodified.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I provided runnable and sources  to test the issue i am facing, you will find it in the bottom of my first message.

Comment: Thanks, but the code should be small enough to post here with your question as code-formatted text, and then should in fact be posted here as an edit to the question, not in a link. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I resolved my problem when trying to make small code to post it here, that was an inattentiveness mistake on my part, i forgot to drop a line that added the component to the JRootPane instead of adding it to the JLayeredPane of the frame.
I explained and formatted my problem in quiet bad way, and i am sorry for that, it was not obvious for me since i am new, i will take your advises to make a better post next time, Thank you for your help